# Access to Actor or Helpers in dataProvider (PhpUnit)

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, codeception

I need to access module and actor in dataProvider method. Unfortunately, there is no progress in [issue](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/862) - tests are initialized before bootstrap, which leads to the problem in the end.

I need this to initizalize module (helper) with fake data generator (and instance of Faker).

Is there any other way than to use trait with necessary initializations and methods or to use another layer in the form of test parent class?

Comment: As a new SO member, I would suggest please go through this section [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have read and checked to find this question. Something is wrong?

Comment: Are you using Laravel framework? In that case you can add `$this->createApplication();` in the dataProvider method before the return statement.

Comment: Nope, Yii2 and Codeception.

Comment: Alright, maybe there is something similar to `$this->createApplication();` in Yii2?

Comment: Hm. This is mega "linguistic crutch". It is not suitable, since it is necessary to create application components and address them, instead of using "legal" module-helper